# Bash puzzle of the week

Tags: bash, environment-variables, parameters

We're having a very strange puzzle related to character encodings and bash replacement, where we are passing a bash variable into a rake script that gets piped into a different bash variable, and I'm not sure what to try next. It only works when you create the variable the non-replace way, but not only do the variables match either way you create them, but even their binary representations match. This *should* exclude anything relating to bad encodings, null-terminators or non-displayable characters. This is one of the most interesting bugs I've ever seen working with any language, so I wanted to share with the community and see if anyone has any ideas for what could be going on here. For further context:

```
RELEASE_CODE=1250
MATCHING=replace
NAME=redactedDeployment-replace-d
```

First, the working case in which the script passes with the expected result.

```
# FULLNAME=redactedDeployment-1250-d
# deployments=$(rake find_deployments[$FULLNAME])
# echo $deployments
redactedDeployment-1250-d
# echo $FULLNAME
redactedDeployment-1250-d
# echo $FULLNAME | perl -lpe '$_=join " ", unpack"(B8)*"'
01110010 01100101 01100100 01100001 01100011 01110100 01100101 01100100 01000100 01100101 01110000 01101100 01101111 01111001 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101101 00110001 00110010 00110101 00110000 00101101 01100100
```

and

```
# if [ "${MATCHING,,}" = "replace" ]; then
>       FULLNAME=${NAME/replace/$RELEASE_CODE}
>       tr -dc '[[:print:]]' <<< "$FULLNAME" #Remove non-printable characters, same result if we remove this line
>     else
>       FULLNAME=${NAME}-${RELEASE_CODE}
>     fi
# deployments=$(rake find_deployments[$FULLNAME])
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'find_deployments[redactedDeployment-1250-d' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
# echo $FULLNAME
redactedDeployment-1250-d
# echo $FULLNAME | perl -lpe '$_=join " ", unpack"(B8)*"'
01110010 01100101 01100100 01100001 01100011 01110100 01100101 01100100 01000100 01100101 01110000 01101100 01101111 01111001 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101101 00110001 00110010 00110101 00110000 00101101 01100100
```

Comment: This line `tr -dc '[[:print:]]' <<< "$FULLNAME"` does not *modify* the FULLNAME variable in any way, so yeah, it's a no-op.

Comment: Check if your script file/rakefile contains `\r\n` line endings: `cat -v file`

Comment: @glennjackman Good to note, doesn't solve the puzzle at hand though with the exact binary matches (fed them thru https://diffchecker.com). I will add that this isn't urgent, I wound up using some sed magic to get it to take in a var not a file, but still very curious why the parameter expansion is broken in this strange way.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're not just missing the trailing `]` in your code for the argument you're passing to `rake`?

Comment: And if you really want to see what's in the variable, you need to quote it. I find `od -c` more readable: `echo "$FULLNAME" | od -c` -- when you leave the variable unquoted, some whitespace characters are removed.

Comment: I think the "one of the most interesting bugs" is in fact user not quoting variables. It only needs `$FULLNAME` to have a trailing space or newline (probably originating in `$RELEASE_CODE`) to trigger this kind of behavior. As said, `tr` is a no-op. And (because of lack of quoting) `echo $FULLNAME` may "hide" the very same characters that are the culprit elsewhere (because of lack of quoting there).

Comment: @glennjackman I posted the same line I used, and I also tried appending one to the code I showed anyway as part of my debugging process. 
 deployments=$(rake find_deployments[$FULLNAME])

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I haven't gone back to try it since my PR was already merged, but I think your answer does resolve the questions I had, certainly seems like a possible explanation if echo does have that behavior without quoting. Appreciate the bash expertise and will use it as a reminder to aggressively quote bash variables in the future but I do think it's a behavior that's really unintuitive to debugging. Does it just trim whitespace on both sides of the output you think?

Comment: `… if echo does have that behavior without quoting` – It's not about `echo`, it's about the shell. Please see the "What happens without the quotes?" part in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).